# trying to connect to non-standard port over esxi guest network

Tags: networking, windows-7, vmware-esxi

I've got an exsi 5.5 box that has a redhat 6.5 guest and a win7 guest.  The guest nics are connected on a vsphere standard switch.  There is no connection from the vswitch to an outside physical nic.

I can ping between the two boxes, each way.

I can successfully psping redhat:22 from the win7 box.

I can successfully tcping win7:139 from the redhat box.

All firewalls are down on both boxes.

I cannot connect from the win7 box to redhat:8003, either via psping redhat:8003, nor telnet redhat 8003, nor by the application client itself.

sudo netstat -patn | grep 8003 on the redhat box shows that it's listening on 0.0.0.0.

Any thoughts?  suggestions?

Comment: that's strange. there's nothing magical about port 8003 and I've made many connections between VMs hosted on esxi on ports in the 8000 range (including 8003). you have any hostname bindings on the redhat box? (what is listening on port 8003)

you have any AV or HIPS products that may be interfering w/network traffic even if the standard firewalls are off?

are you trying to make an ipv6 connection when you're trying to connect to port 8003?

Comment: I know you said "firewalls are down", but that's not exactly a precise statement. How about the output of from the RH box: sudo iptables -L -nv

Comment: Magellan: hm, you're right now that I'm looking at it today.  How about 'firewalls are full open ip any any in and out".  8)  Anyway problem solved (see answer). Sort of.

Answer (score 0):

Well, had to reboot the esxi box for unrelated reasons before I left yesterday.  When I got in this morning and got back on this issue, there was no issue.  So, problem resolved, if not actually solved.

Kinda leaves me uneasy actually, but moving on....